# How can I merge responses of two Google Form identical to each other but in two different languages

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I want to combine the responses of two of my Google Forms that are identical to each other but in two different languages. How can I combine the responses to get the summary of both sets of responses?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. There are many ways to do that. What have you tried so far? Is this something that should be done only once or continuously? Are you already sending the form responses to an spreadsheet? How many questions and responses do your forms have or do you expect that they will have?

Answer (score 0):

You have two Google Forms. They are identical except that they are in different languages. You want a summary of the combined responses.

---

Use `QUERY` to create an array that combines the results of two separate queries - one for each Form Response sheet.

The query should be something like this:

`={query({'Form Responses 1'!A1:A,'Form Responses 1'!B1:B,'Form Responses 1'!C1:C}, "select Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null",0);query({'Form Responses 2'!A1:A,'Form Responses 2'!B1:B,'Form Responses 2'!C1:C}, "select Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null",0)}`

The key aspects are:

- create a query for each form
- create an array using curly brackets
- combine the queries between the curly brackets using a semicolon (`;`) to combine/stack the output from each query
- create your own column headers

---

**Example**

The query is in Cell A3

[image: Combined]

---

**Responses - Form#1 (French)**

[image: form1]

---

**Responses - Form#2 (Maltese)**

[image: form2]